# How to replace substring from df1['Column 1'] with values from df2['Column 2'] when df1['Column 1'] contains df2['Column 1']?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

How to replace substring from df1['Column 1'] with values from df2['Column 2'] when df1['Column 1'] contains df2['Column 1']?

df1:

| Column1 |
| --- |
| A&O Inc. |
| HP Canada |

df2:

| Column1 | Column2 |
| --- | --- |
| A&O | Allen & Overy |
| HP | Hewlett Packard |

Expected Output:

| Column1 |
| --- |
| Allen & Overy Inc. |
| Hewlett Packard Canada |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can craft a regex to use with [`str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) and a function as replacement to fetch the matching name:

```
import re

s = df2.set_index('Column1')['Column2']

pattern = re.compile('|'.join(map(re.escape, s.index)))
# re.compile(r'A\&O|HP', re.UNICODE)

df1['out'] = df1['Column1'].str.replace(pattern, lambda m: s.get(m.group(0)),
                                        regex=True)
```

Alternatively, if performance is not important, you can also use [`replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) (note that this will loop over all possible replacements and thus be slow for many values):

```
s = df2.set_index('Column1')['Column2']

df1['out'] = df1['Column1'].replace(s.to_dict(), regex=True)
```

Output `df1`:

```
     Column1                     out
0   A&O Inc.      Allen & Overy Inc.
1  HP Canada  Hewlett Packard Canada
```

Comment: awesome! thanks a lot. Is there a course that you could recommend me to learn to create this kind of things? Thanks!

Comment: No, I mostly use the official documentation and SO as sources ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
for index, row in df2.iterrows():
    df1['Column1'] = df1['Column1'].str.replace(row['Column1'], row['Column2'])
```

It works with your example.

df1:

```
       Column1
0  Allen & Overy Inc.
1  Hewlett Packard Canada
```